# Question about the inverse function and the implicit function theorems.

Tags: implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

The theorems in question are[image]
and[image]
A consecuence of (9.24) is [image]
and a consecuence of (9.28) is the following highlighted text [image]
I'm having trouble at how he arrived a these conclusions